# multiple files inking undefined reference - extern

Tags: c++, extern, undefined-reference

I have a relatively large project and I am using the same syntax as in a previous version of the project where it worked fine.

in file Main.cpp:

```
#include "Note.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

std::ofstream  *notaFile;
int main(int parameterCount, char **parameterList) {
  notaFile = new std::ofstream("Notation.txt", ios::out);
}
```

in file Note.h

```
extern std::ofstream *notaFile;
```

in file Note.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void Note::setPitchWellTempered(int absPitchNum) {

   *notaFile << "Octave Number " << octaveNum << endl;
}
```

when linking:

```
lib/liblcmod.a(Note.o): In function `Note::setPitchWellTempered(int)':
CMOD/src/Note.cpp:117: undefined reference to `notaFile'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Probably more information you'll actually need, but I'm sure you'll find your answer in the duplicate.

Comment: This might be actually kinda tricky, if the Note.cpp is part of a static library linked to Main.cpp later. Because to actually satisfy the notaFile external it might be necessary that the Main.o appears on the command line after the liblcmod.a. I would in general prefer to move the notaFile declaration to Note.cpp, i.e. into the library.